# folder created within an api service not loading

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I created an app service at http://testsam.controltrackonline.com, it loads properly. I have also created a folder within it called webapi but it does not load up and does not allow publishing content to it via appVeyor. The non loading folder location can be loaded here http://testsam.controltrackonline.com/webapi

I do not see any permissions issues surrounding this as other app services with same settings load well with folder within. But for this appservice there seems to an issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you'd like to publish content to an Azure web app virtual directory, so please make sure you configure virtual directory or application under [Application settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure) blade in the Azure Portal.

Note: you can also refer to "[Deploying multiple virtual directories to a single Azure Website](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/09/21/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website/)" to set up the virtual directory or application.

> I have also created a folder within it called webapi but it does not load up and does not allow publishing content to it via appVeyor.
>
> I do not see any permissions issues surrounding this as other app services with same settings load well with folder within. But for this appservice there seems to an issue.

Please try to use FTP or [Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) to access your Azure web site folder, and then you can try to upload your content package to `webapi` folder and check if it works as expected.

Besides, If issue only appear on that specific app service, you can create an [Azure support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request), Azure support can help you investigate the issue.